# Flutter Here SDK crashes phone on iOS 17

Tags: flutter, dart, heremaps

I'm having problems initialising the HERE SDK for Flutter with the latest version of the Explore SDK and iOS 17 on a physical device, while on the simulator it works.

This is the initialisation method

```dart
void _initializeHERESDK(String hereApiKeySecret) async {
  // Needs to be called before accessing SDKOptions to load necessary libraries.
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);

  // Set your credentials for the HERE SDK.
  String accessKeyId = "<myAccessKey>";
  SDKOptions sdkOptions = SDKOptions.withAccessKeySecret(accessKeyId, hereApiKeySecret);

  try {
    await SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(sdkOptions);
  } on InstantiationException {
    throw Exception("Failed to initialize the HERE SDK.");
  }
}
```

The line that seems to break the app and reboot the phone is this one

```dart
await SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(sdkOptions);
```

I'm using Flutter 3.13.8 and the Explore edition 4.16.1.0 released on 23 Oct 2023.

I also tried to add just the initialisation method to the Flutter demo app and calling it when a button is pressed instead of calling it in the initState but it still rebooted the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the Flutter version, reverting to 3.10.5 fixed the problem